# Is StreamTransformer concurrent safe?

Tags: ignite

Suppose that I have a ignite cluster with several nodes and a partitioned non-empty IgniteCache named "TEST_CACHE". Then I run following code in one of nodes:

```
ignite.compute().run(new IgniteRunnable(){
    @IgniteInstanceResource
    private Ignite ignite;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        IgniteDataStreamer<String,Long> ds = ignite.dataStreamer("TEST_CACHE");
        ds.receiver(new StreamTransformer<String,Long>(){
            @Override
            public Object process(MutableEntry<String, Long> entry, Object... arguments)
                    throws EntryProcessorException {
                Long value = entry.getValue();
                entry.setValue(value==null?1L:(value.longValue()+1L));
                return null;
            }
        });

        //loop for adding lots of String data
        while(...)
            ds.addData(...);
    }

});
```

This is similar to the offical StreamTransformerExample code, but what different is each node will get a DataStreamer instance of a same cache, and invoke addData method concurrently. In other words, for the same string data in different nodes, maybe one node has just got the value by "Long value = entry.getValue()" but not execute next row code to set value and update into cache, then another node is executing "entry.getValue()". So is it possible to update wrong value in this concurrent StreamTransformer use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StreamReceiver.receive calls cache.invoke with your entry processor, so entry is locked within this operation. So yes, it is concurrent safe.

BTW, did you enable allowOverwrite in your DataStreamer?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't enable allowOverwrite. Does allowOverwrite influence concurrent safety?

Comment: It dosn't, but: "By default, the data streamer will not overwrite existing data, which means that if it will encounter an entry that is already in cache, it will skip it".

Comment: OK, I see. I just want to use DataStreamer.receiver for implement group as sql

Comment: You can also use [ComputeTask](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/compute-tasks#computetask) for map-reduce calculations